# Websocket over MQTT by Mosquitto 1.6.10

Tags: websocket, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I have problem with using Websocket on MQTT by Mosquitto.

I'm using raspberry pi as a broker, and want to publish some information, subscribe on web.

Former method (in 1.4.10 version etc.) is to add those two lines

====================

listener 9001

protocol websockets

====================

in /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf or /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/(certain .conf file)

and modify allowance about Websocket in config.mk to [yes]

but in 1.6.10 version, perticularly in raspberrypi, I can't find
the config.mk file so it doesn't works.

Can anybody tell me where's config.mk or if there's any other method to use Websocket on rasp.pi?

Comment: How are you installing mosquito?

Comment: @romkey I installed mosquitto according to the manual of raspberry pi installation on Eclipse Mosquitto

Comment: @romkey the Mosquitto Debian Repository

Comment: If you are installing the pre-built binary there is no `config.mk`. It is only used to turn on/off features when building mosquitto and the pre-built versions should already have websockets enabled

Comment: @hadillb Thank you very much, but still, my websockets are not working all lol I'd better install by another method : which is not pre-built one

Comment: @hadillb It worked properly in the way by installing gzip file, modifying the .mk file!! Thanks for your help, sir! You made my day!